# How To Open A New Webpage To The LEFT Of Current Webpage's Browser Tab

Tags: html

I have several webpages open.  One webpage has a link to open a new webpage.  If I use _self it opens inplace of the current one, not acceptable.  If I use _blank it preserves the current one but opens to the right of the current browser tab.  Not acceptable.  How to preserve the current one and open to the left of the current browser tab?

```
    <a href="http://www.chasertool.xyz/index.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">HOME - Chaser Tool</a>


    <a href="http://www.chasertool.xyz/index.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">HOME - Chaser Tool</a>
```

See above please.

Comment: You cannot control this via HTML or JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can't without change the browser settings.

You can sort of 'hack' it like this:

```html
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="location.href='http://www.microsoft.com';" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

The onclick attribute will open on the left (the existing tab) while the href on the right (the _blank target).

Comment: so you can put your existing page as the onclick target and the desired "left tab" as the href... or vice versa. This is the reason i wrote "hack" (:

Comment: then are you forced to refresh the page?

Comment: probably yes... can't think of something better... i did searched for it also cause this interesting. Good luck with that

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The placement of the tab is controlled by the browser, so you can't control this from a webpage.

However, if you change your browser language to RTL language, such as Arabic or Hebrew, new tabs will open to the left of the current tab.